# Where is the account data for Helldivers 2 on PC?

Tags: helldivers-2

I've been looking for it on AppData/Roaming/Arrowhead/Helldivers2 but nothing seems like it is it. As a multiplayer game, it's probably that only the account data is required, and somehow it gets it from steam, but I can't find that either. I don't want to attach a debugger, because that would definitively trigger the anti-cheat. How does Helldivers 2 keep my account data and where is it?